# ERROR EN 1452, No se puede agregar o actualizar una fila secundaria: falla una restricción de clave externa

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysqldb

Este es el error:

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bancoprueba`.`movcuentas`, CONSTRAINT `movcuentas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ncta`) REFERENCES `cuentas` (`ncta`))

---

Este es mi código:

```
-- Tabla de Cuentas de Ahorro
create table Cuentas
(
ncta char(1) not null primary key,       -- Numero de Cuenta
dcta char(15) not null,                       -- Descripcion de la Cuenta
propietario char(40) not null,              -- Nombre del propietario
fecha date not null                            -- Fecha de inicio
); 
-- Tabla de Movimientos de la Cuenta de Ahorros
create table MovCuentas
(
ntran integer  not null,             -- Nro Movimiento
ncta char(1) not null,              -- Nro de Cuenta          
fecha date not null,                -- Fecha del Mvimiento
impt decimal,                        -- si impt>0 es abono, si impt<0 es retiro
check (impt<>0),
foreign key(ncta) references Cuentas(ncta),
primary key(ntran,ncta)
);

SELECT @monto=750; 
insert MovCuentas VALUES(3,'A', current_timestamp (),-@monto);//EN ESTOS DOS CAMPOS ME SALE ESE ERROR
insert INTO MovCuentas VALUES(3,'B', now(),@monto);//
```

Comment: Pues eso. Tiene que haber un registro en cuentas que tenga `A` en `ncta` **antes** de insertar en MovCuentas. ¿Tienes claro cómo funciona una foreign key?

Comment: En tu tabla `Cuentas`, hay registros donde el campo `ncta` sea "A" y "B"?

Comment: @JuanRivera touche, no no hay registros, si recién me di cuenta q no había ejecutado los registros ‍♀️